# How to apply CSS to a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, textbox

I have this code, and it renders this HTML. How can I apply CSS to my control if they are named ctrctrctr-00000 or something else like that that is only useful to the VIEWSTATE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="../global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
Informacion General: Paises
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Pais.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTUyMDk1NTY2MGRkwAKu2OIV85kXfcUcAefBBNmSuRY=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwLSha7NBAKqw7ARAvjQlaIKhJ2HMftmmOoxe/+aE4sG3D32QtA=" />
</div>
    <div>

    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPais" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPais" />
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Frontend._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <h1>Prueba de Escritorio</h1>        
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPais" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Guardar" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I use a CSS selector to target ALL textboxes on the page regardless of name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it a CSS class, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPais" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" />
```

Then just use add what you need in your CSS:

```
.textbox { color: red; }
```

The [`CssClass` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(VS.71).aspx) doesn't get mangled like the ID and name attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Much clearer answer. However it's not working as expected. I set the CssClass attribute, created the CSS rule; during testing while viewing source I can see that the CSS file is being correctly linked, but no change. I also notice the normal HTML code for the textbox doesn't have a reference to my css class at all. What would cause this?

Comment: @Sergio - Is the CssClass getting changed anywhere else?  The HTML for my example above should render `class="textbox"` as a property on the `<input>`.

Comment: OK, I added ANOTHER textbox to see if the testing server isn't relaying new information and that's the case. It's not showing the newest additions. How can I make sure that the testing server shows me the latest stuff? I mean the ASP.Net Development server.

Comment: @Sergio - that happens sometimes, either a server restart or a re-compile *usually* forces it to re-cache, if that doesn't work blow away the temporary files under your Microsot.Net\Framework folder (in the rare case it *really* won't let go).

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you do this either:

```
input[type=text] { /* style */ } (standard)
```

or

```
input.text { /* style */ } (not as standard)
```

???

Comment: That would effect all text boxes on any page the stylesheet is linked to.  If that is what he wants then there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: even if you do not want this to be applied to all textboxes in all pages, just apply a class or ID to the parent div and use hierarchy to specify selective text boxes 

eg:  `.specefic-area input[type=text] { /* style */ } `

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery and do it like this:

```
$('input[id$=_txt]').addClass('yourClassName maybeAnotherClassName');
```

Comment: What does $('input[id$=_txt]') do?

Comment: @Sergio - This answer would require jQuery...and is definitely not the correct way to go about this :)

Comment: It matches an input fields that contain '_txt' in their id

Comment: You would use this for something like if you wanted to change the class of the textbox onclick using javascript.  I wasn't thinking so simply as Nick down below :)

Comment: It selects all IDs that *end* in `_txt`, `*=` would be contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type=text]").addClass("textBoxCSS");
        }
```

For applying classes to text boxes on a page, you can further customize the selectors and be more specific.